# Most efficient way to get all files in a directory

Tags: macos, mac, bash, filesystem, command-line

I have a million+ files spread across four fiber-connected arrays. I need to get the path, filesize, and last_modified date to insert into a mysql database. What would be the best way to do this?

Here is what I am currently doing:

```
sudo find "$FULFILLMENT" "$ARCH1" "$ARCH2" "$MASTERING" -type f -exec ls -lT {} + > $FILE
```

And then I parse that file (using Python) to insert it into my db.

What would be the best way to accomplish the above?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with what you are currently doing? Also, I don't see how we can answer this properly without some insight on which files and on what location you need to search.

Comment: There are a millions files spread across four volumes. They're all types of files (really, it's four different computers with 100's of TB storage each). What I'm currently doing takes about 3 hours, I was wondering if there's something that is faster.

Comment: And how much of those 3 hours does the `find` command take to complete? In any case, I do believe `find` is the most appropriate tool for listing the files.

Comment: The `find` command takes about 99% of the time.

Comment: You could try `find -type f -ls`, though I'm not sure that will make any significant difference. It sounds like there just is a lot of data to process.

Comment: Have you tried doing the entire thing in python, and inserting into the DB directly? Piping the output of `ls` to a file, then parsing it later, adds avoidable overhead. Check out the `os.path` API: http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html